# sap.m.select bound to ODATA - literal lookup

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a SAP UI5 form that includes a select control which is bound to my default odata service.

This binding is two way and I'm able to read and post entities back into SAP.

My problem is the underlying data model stores several fields as 1 character flags in the database table, e.g. C = Customer, O = Org etc.

Where is the best place for me to convert these 1 character values into their literal equivalents? (i.e. to display as the 'text' for my dropdown values/on other UI controls).

Should I be doing this conversion at the UI level, or back in the SAP OData service? Can I get your collective thoughts on what the best practice approach is here?

Cheers

Comment: definitely on the backend. It should add the description field and you will just map this description field to the "text" or "description" property in your Select/ComoboBox bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Agree you should favour the backend for this - in fact it would be unusual if the SAP backend doesn't already have texts associated with these values that you would just need to expose in your oData service. Added bonus is that these texts should be translatable so if you need to support multiple languages the backend will look after this for you.